# Why is a ternary conditional avoided in libstdc++ implementation of std::max?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

In libstdc++ implementation of the `<algorithm>` header, part of which on my system resides in `/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h`, I can see the following implementation of `std::max`:

```
template<typename _Tp>
  _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
  inline const _Tp&
  max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
  {
    // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_Tp>)
    //return  __a < __b ? __b : __a;
    if (__a < __b)
      return __b;
    return __a;
  }
```

You can see that the single statement with the ternary conditional operator `?:` is commented out, and the `if`-based code is used instead.

I suppose there's some technical reason for this. So what can go wrong with the commented out version and not with the active one? Or are they exactly equivalent, and the active version simply makes step-by-step debugging easier?

Comment: Use git history to find out who commented that out and why.

Comment: @ChristopherYeleighton oh, I've tried. The commit message doesn't clarify this in the slightest: [4fd97a6380d82d3f3ac8c5ee1dcdab7181794c13](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/4fd97a6380d82d3f3ac8c5ee1dcdab7181794c13)

Comment: `2012-09-23  Paolo Carlini  <paolo.carlini@oracle.com>

 Revert:
 2012-09-21  Paolo Carlini  <paolo.carlini@oracle.com>` xd [Och well. Looks like just can't make up his mind, can he?](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/88a4c78be1f44b8918517382b628f2062c30c834) and then [we go back once again](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/ffa67767d08dbb9666c6e128d0273950cf4934b8#diff-2a513570122a7958084d91dd2513aca9L1490)

Comment: Maybe it's just a style convention? As far as I know both are equal and the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: Well, if this was a revert than maybe the original commit would shed some light?

Comment: @ChristopherYeleighton see the link in KamilCuk's comment

Comment: And [the comment was `//return` there from 20 years ago](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/725dc051cada61aca8127f1062ec97a31acf79f1/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algobase.h#L116). I think at this point the easiest way is most probably mail Paolo Carlini and ask him.

Comment: There were conditional operator implementation bugs in gcc like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53000 maybe this is to avoid those.

Comment: @dewaffled from the Bugzilla thread this seems indeed to be the answer.

Comment: not sure, but ternary operator may create a third (useless ?) object,  not if. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Saint-Martin no, why would it?

Comment: __a < __b ? __b : __a; is a new object. but __a and __b are existing objects ?

Comment: @Saint-Martin if types of `__a` and `__b` are the same (as they are in the code above), then the value of the expression is a reference, not a new object. Inspect the error message that GCC gives for the following code (namely, note the template parameter of `helper` in the error message): `template<typename T> struct helper{};

int main()
{
    int x=3, y=7;
    struct S{} s=helper<decltype(x?x:y)>{};
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were conditional operator implementation bugs in gcc like https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53000. Probably this is to avoid those.